# Calculating the Spell Resistance benefit of a summoned creature with the Celestial Template

Tags: pathfinder-1e, summoning

When calculating the Spell Resistance benefit of a summoned creature with the Celestial template, the template adds 1 CR if the creature has 5 HD or more. The spell resistance factor is based on 5 + the CR.

Do we use the original CR of the monster, or the new one after the CR adjustment of the celestial template?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Use the [celestial creature](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/bestiary/monsterAdvancement.html#celestial-creature)'s updated CR to determine its SR

The template [celestial creature](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/bestiary/monsterAdvancement.html#celestial-creature) on Rebuild Rules (that are used when creating a whole new stat block for a creature) on Defensive Abilities says the a creature to which the celestial creature template's been applied "gains SR equal to *new* CR +5" (emphasis mine).